# How would I create this trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables that look like this (of course they have a lot more rows).

```
AuthorID | Name          | Number of albums
-------------------------------------------
1        | Santana       | 39
2        | Johnny Cash   | 95

AuthorID | AlbumID     
----------------------
1        | 14    
2        | 17
```

What I want to do is have a trigget that gets updated when there is a row deleted or inserted into the second table. The row I want to update in the first table is the 3rd row. Which basically represents `count(AlbumID)` that is  also how I have calculated it. I don't really know how I would do that since until now I only created really simple triggers

Comment: And why not calculate that value in a select when needed?

Comment: @juergend want the tables be up to date and not update them manually since the rows will also be deleted and insterted automatically with a program

Comment: But why store the value at all? If you need the count then just calculate it on-the-fly in a `select` query.

Comment: Or create a view that holds that calculated value if you really must

Comment: @juergend ok thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear why you need to store a number_of_albums column in the first place. But I won't address that question. I'll answer the question you asked.

An after insert trigger on the second table can perform an update the first table, to increment the number_of_albums column for the given author_id. We'll assume the name of the first table is `author` and the name of the second table is `album`.

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE TRIGGER album_ai 
 AFTER INSERT ON album 
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN 
   UPDATE author 
      SET number_of_albums = number_of_albums + 1
    WHERE author_id = NEW.author_id;
 END$$    

 DELIMITER ;
```

You could do something similar with an after delete trigger, decrementing the `number_of_albums` column, referencing `OLD.author_id` to get the value of the `author_id` column of the row that is deleted.

For an update, if the value of the `author_id` column is changed, you would need to update two rows... increment number_of_albums on one row, and decrement number_of_albums the other.

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE TRIGGER album_ai 
 AFTER UPDATE ON album 
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   IF NOT ( NEW.author_id <=> OLD.author_id ) THEN  
     UPDATE author
        SET number_of_albums = number_of_albums - 1
      WHERE author_id = OLD.author_id;
     UPDATE author
        SET number_of_albums = number_of_albums + 1
      WHERE author_id = NEW.author_id;
   END IF;
 END$$    

 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: does mysql undersatand upsert in trigger?

Comment: MySQL supports triggers both BEFORE and AFTER both INSERT and UPDATE. MySQL doesn't support "upsert", except for an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement. And MySQL will invoke the appropriate INSERT and/or UPDATE triggers.